# SQL: Performance vs Readability

Tags: sql, database-performance

Is it a good idea to use string based primary keys for readability reasons? Or should you always use integers?

I know about integer versus string comparison complexity. But is this even an issue on modern hardware? I'm thinking about a medium-size web application (50-100 simultaneous users).

**Edit:**
By "readability" I mean being able to easily/quickly comprehend the relations between tables.

Lesser readable:

```
# UserID|DepartmentID
# ------|------------
# 732   |5
# 812   |3

INSERT INTO `UserDepartment` VALUES ('732','5');
INSERT INTO `UserDepartment` VALUES ('812','3');
```

More readable:

```
# UserID    |DepartmentID
# ----------|------------
# Bill Gates|R&D
# Steve Jobs|Finance

INSERT INTO `UserDepartment` VALUES ('Bill Gates','R&D');
INSERT INTO `UserDepartment` VALUES ('Steve Jobs','Finance');
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this point .. "for readability reasons? "  and also tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: Please Explain your Idea a bit more.
Basically never do premature optimization. Readabitlity is Key unless Performance is a real-world problem.

But i'm not sure if your Idea really is more readable at all.
You are going against the best practice here, keep that in mind.

Comment: Try to imagine what you need to do if someone made a typing error. and you need to correct it. ('Bill Gates' -->> 'Gill Bates') Now suppose this PK is also used as an FK in some othere table ...)

Answer (score 0):

The question is why would you read it.
Primary key is a technical feature, so use it as effective as possible. Just use another field to add readability strings.

It *might be* a minor issue for what you've planned. But in case of growth it may be a huge pain and it wouldn't be so easy to change your data structure. It also may become a problem for some complex queries. And don't forget that it's not just about simultaneous connections - what about your data? You may store three strings and yes - it's gonna be alright. But what happens when you have millions of items? Even simple SELECT might be slow and every of your 50 users would probably be upset.

The answer is no - it's not a good idea. They call it best practice for a reason, so make your product great from the very beginning.

Comment: For instance if you have an extra table called `status` then you would have to join every time against that table to get the `status_name` from the `ID` in another table. If you use the name as primary key then you don't have to join at all to get the status name in a query.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. You're saying that primary keys are technical features and I wouldn't read them anyways. But then how do you initialize your databases? Creating thousands of lines such as `INSERT INTO \`XYZ\` VALUES ('732','5','76');` is extremely time-consuming and error-prone (in my opinion).

Comment: @Lugaxx Any DBMS worth using has autoincrement (or similar) functionality for creating unique primary keys automatically. For example MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: @evsheino Using auto-increment helps if you're creating "independent" entries. But if you have relations in your tables you will still have to deal with these inexpressive integer values. For example, if you wanted to reference "Bill Gates" in a table called "EmployeeOfTheMonth", you would still have to look up his primary key (integer value) first. I don't know... I find that quite annoying.

Comment: @Lugaxx What if another Bill Gates gets a job at the same place? Or Bill Gates changes his name to something else? I know that's an artificial example, but you still have to use something other than a name to identify a person in a db, and then you will end up with something that is not very human-readable anyway. I have nothing against natural primary keys, but readability should not be the main concern when choosing them over synthetic ones. Also, looking up a primary key based on another value should not be an issue...

Comment: @Lugaxx that's why you create an application - to operate with your entities in a natural way. You select everything from EmployeeOfTheMonth, and while you work with "Bill Gates" and "R&D" strings at the GUI, your app creates numeric values under the hood. You can choose strings as primary key if you are absolutely sure that your DB is read-only and you're gonna insert all the values by yourself. Otherwise, name won't be a unique identifier, as evsheino mentioned above.

Comment: @juergend frankly, I don't get it. If we had a table called `status` we wouldn't store the name of status at another table. We would store the information about this status and join other entities - let's say employees - with this status by ID. Otherwise we would just add the `status` column to the `employees` table.

Comment: @Smileek: Sure but when just adding a `status` column to the `employee` table we could just put everything in that column we want. But with a foreign key only defined status are allowed.

Comment: @juergend absolutely. But that's not the same case: it's whether we have foreign keys or use the same table. The question is more about having few tables linked via strings instead of numbers. Foreign key VS column is simple: if we have more information about status than just a name, or if there are other tables linked with the same statuses, we use foreign key. Otherwise, column will be enough. That's simplified, of course, but it's the main idea for general cases.

Comment: @Smileek: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31b1ec/1. As you can see I can query only the `employee` table to get the status also. No need to join and I can't just put everything I want into the `status` column of `emplyee`.

Comment: @juergend that's a good point. As I've already mentioned, it may work fine for tiny tables filled manually. But in case of table dynamically filled from the app you probably will have to create it without clustered index, otherwise `insert` will be painful most of the time. To sum up, numeric primary key is a technical feature, which is scalable and provides the best performance. If performance is not the case, it's possible to avoid it. But one has to be sure that performance is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the choice between synthetic primary keys versus natural primary keys.  Let me say up front that I am in big proponent of synthetic primary keys.  That doesn't mean that natural primary keys are never useful, but I admit to the bias.

Why do I prefer synthetic keys (say, auto-incremented numeric keys)?  Let me count the says:

- They guarantee uniqueness.
- They provide a record of the order of insertion into the table.
- They are typically four bytes, and fixed byte fields are more efficient for indexes.
- They are a single column; composite primary keys can be quite cumbersome.

Of course, they might incur a small amount of overhead.

Another big issue is that the "natural" key might change.  For instance, something like an account number might change if we learn that two accounts are really the same person.  Having the "natural" primary key as an attribute makes fixing this easy; just change the value in the table.  Of course, cascading update foreign keys do provide another solution.

I can think of one case where a natural primary key is useful.  Sometimes, we want to validate a string value -- such as "open" or "closed" for status.  This can be handled using a foreign key to a reference table.  Of course, this can also be handled using a `check` constraint on the table.

Comment: How do you usually initialize your database with values? Do you use a "raw" .sql file containing instructions such as `INSERT INTO \`XYZ\` VALUES ('732','5','76');`? Or do you utilize a "high-level" interface (e.g. `createUser(user, department, ...)`) which handles all the "low-level" `INSERT` instructions?

Comment: I would insert into one table at a time and then use `join`s to look up the ids in the other tables.